# How to use XQuery in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xquery

How to use XQuery expression on XMLDocument or XDocument?

Is it possible to use XQuery in C#?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have a function in sql that do some work on xml using XQuery. I need to insert some data that returned by this function from c# to a sql table and for this I must first, connect and execute this function from c# and then insert this data using Entity framework to sql but I want to connect just one time if it's possible & run the function in C# then connect to insert the result to sql!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure there are a number of XQuery processors that run in .NET, for example XQSharp and Saxon.

Answer (score 2):

Just refer this [Xquery in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24766/Using-Saxon-XSL-2-0-and-XQuery-1-0-in-NET)